# Android key hold repeatedly generating event

Tags: java, android

Is it normal that when you press and hold the Dpad key (or any other 
keys), it will first generate 1 key event, and after like 1 second or 
2, it will then generate other key events repeatedly, as long as you 
are still pressing the key?? I am trying to write a game and want to 
use the Dpad as the game control, but the 1~2 second delay is a 
problem to me. Any workaround?

Comment: thanks. for not helping me at all.

Answer (score 1):

What android event are you using? Is it one of the standard ones, or is it custom written event handling.

As a consideration have you looked at the onKeyDown(int KeyCode, KeyEvent event)?
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onKeyDown(int, android.view.KeyEvent)

Should help you handle the event more gracefully, as you should only get the event called once. Haven't used it myself, but worth a look at.